# Resize post thumbnail

Tags: php, images, post-thumbnails

I'm trying to ensure that all assets are the same size, no matter what resolution they are uploaded in. I'm stuck finding outdated info on the matter, I think.

I've gotten to the following snippet

```
if( get_the_post_thumbnail_url()){
    $image = wp_get_image_editor(get_the_post_thumbnail_url());
    if ( !is_wp_error( $image )){
        $image->resize( 300, 300, true );
        $image->save("image.jpg");
    }
}
```

Which seems to work, but I have no idea how I get the resized URL (or insert it properly). As I want to add it to my page.
Something like

```
echo '<img src=" . $image.url() . ">";
```

Is what I'm thinking of.
Am I going about this wrong, or how should I continue from here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use this `add_image_size( 'custom-thumbnail', 300, 300, true );` in `funtions.php`

and call it `<img src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url('custom-thumbnail'); ?>">` in your page?

Comment: I tried added those two lines you mentioned. One in function.php and the other in my template. Nothing appears from that

Comment: I figured it out. Good tip with add_image_size that's definitely the way to go, thanks!

Comment: glad that help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe providing ID may help.

```
if( get_the_post_thumbnail_url()){
    $image = wp_get_image_editor(get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID()));
    if ( !is_wp_error( $image )){
        $image->resize( 300, 300, true );
        $image->save("image.jpg");
    }
}
```

Comment: The issue is I don't know how to write the image to the page, it works just fine without an ID

Comment: What do you mean by write to the page.

Comment: I want to add the resized image to my page